# How to slice part of field from 'list' view – django rest framework

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I make a news aggregator based on Django REST Framework. My model 'Article' has values:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    source = models.CharField(max_length=55)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    link = models.URLField(max_length=255)
    text = models.TextField()
    import_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

And I have a serializer for it:

```
class ArticleSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ['url', 'source', 'title', 'text', 'link']
```

But I have a little trouble with making view for articles. When view method is 'list' it has to show just first 700 characters of 'text' field (like text[:700]) and only if I move to detail view of an article, it will show full text.

I tried to make field 'text_preview' in 'Article' model and second serializer without 'text' field but with 'text_preview'. It isn't good to store 700 characters of similar text in database and create almost similar serializers. Maybe you people any smart method to do it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a separate serializer for the ***list view*** and use [**`SerializerMethodField`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) as

```
class ArticleSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ['url', 'source', 'title', 'text', 'link']


class ArticleListSerializer(ArticleSerializer):
    text = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_text(self, article):
        return article.text[:700]
```